# Remove duplicate chars from String

Tags: java, strings

I have retackled this problem using the help I received from here: [Remove duplications from a Java String](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166984/remove-duplications-from-a-java-string) but this time using a `LinkedHashSet` since previosuly I was using a `HashSet` but the answer was out of order.

From this implementation my run time should be \$O(n)\$ correct?
Does anyone see any room where I can improve my code or some mistakes?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String test = "Banana";
    LinkedHashSet knownChars = new LinkedHashSet();
    StringBuilder noDups = new StringBuilder();

    for(Character c : test.toCharArray()){
        if(!knownChars.contains(c)){
            knownChars.add(c);
            noDups.append(c);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("No duplicate string is: " + noDups);
}
```

Comment: This approach works, but why are you using a LinkedHashSet? Just use a HashSet and it should work fine as well.

Comment: I was previously using a HashSet but, the results would be printed out of order. For example, given the string , "Banana" the result would be "aBn" still correct but not in order.

Comment: You can just say *O(n)*, no need to say *BigO* everytime.

Comment: You should tell that your code is based on [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/167003/35991) to your previous question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below points are in no particular order:

### Extraction into Methods

1. The utility and the test should be broken up into methods, i.e., you should have a function `String removeDuplicates(String)`, containing the logic for removing duplicates.

### Manual Boxing

2. Unnecessary manual boxing to `Character`, just use `char` and let `javac` take care of it on its own (JDK1.5+ supports autoboxing of primitives).

### Why `LinkedHashSet`?

3. A `HashSet` can be used just fine here - the order of the resulting deduplicated `String` is determined by the order of insertion of characters into the `StringBuilder`, not the `HashSet`. (*Believe me, I checked.* Here you can also: http://ideone.com/K9Ku2p)
4. Note that the `add` method of `Set`s return a `boolean`, `true` if the set did not already contain the element and it has been added successfully, or `false` if the element was already present in the `Set`. Exploiting this makes the call to `Set.contains(...)` redundant, see the example code.

### Generics

5. Use generics. Don't use raw collections - they can violate type safety. In your case, you might not realise the immediate benefit of doing so, but it is a good practice when scaling to larger programs. Here, using generics is as simple as changing `LinkedHashSet knownChars = new LinkedHashSet();` to `LinkedHashSet<Character> knownChars = new LinkedHashSet<>();` (JDK 1.7+ to get the diamond type inference, otherwise it has to be `LinkedHashSet<Character> knownChars = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();`, JDK 1.5+)

### Space-time tradeoffs

6. To minimize the number of reallocations of the underlying buffers of `StringBuilder` or `HashSet`, initialize them with a default capacity of the largest possible size they could have, which is the length of the input `String`. Use the constructors which have an `int capacity` parameter. See the example code for details.
7. To avoid a `gotcha` involving the load factor (a parameter which decides how full a `HashSet` should be before it is resized) of the `HashSet` when initializing the `HashSet` with capacity in point 6 (the `Hashset` may be prematurely resized), also set the load factor to `1.0f`, using the `new HashSet(int capacity, float loadFactor)` constructor overload.

### Miscellaneous

8. Type to interfaces, e.g., use `Set<Character> knownChars = new LinkedHashSet<>();` instead of `LinkedHashSet<Character> knownChars = new LinkedHashSet<>();`. This makes your code in general more resilient to refactoring, you can use a different `Set` implementation at any time by changing one word instead of 2.
9. Qualify your method parameters with `final` if you are not going to reassign them in any way - granted, `String` being immutable makes this redundant, in the sense that any reassignments done to `input` in `removeDuplicates` will not affect `test` in `main`, but it's a good practice anyway.
10. Better output messages - see the example code for an example.
11. Better variable naming - it's already quite good, but try to use full words. See the example code.

### Example Code ([Ideone](http://ideone.com/welRit)):

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;

// Store in a file `StringUtilities.java`
public class StringUtilities
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String test = "Banana";

        System.out.println("Test string \"" + test + "\" with duplicates removed is: \"" + removeDuplicates(test) + "\"");
    }
    
    public static String removeDuplicates(final String input) {
        Set<Character> knownCharacters = new HashSet<>(input.length(), 1.0f);
        StringBuilder noDuplicates = new StringBuilder(input.length());

        for(char character : input.toCharArray()){
            if(knownCharacters.add(character)){
                noDuplicates.append(character);
            }
        }
        return noDuplicates.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: @mdfst13, Thanks for catching that terminology issue there between functions and methods, guess I've been doing too much Scala recently. I normally consider static methods not accessing state to be functions in Java, but I agree that using methods everywhere is more consistent. Also, by that redundancy comment I meant that since String is immutable, the caller's copy of whatever was passed to `input` wouldn't be altered either way - I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: The maximal capacity of the set should be larger (length * 4 / 3) if resizing should be avoided as the parameter represents the internal array size, not the resize threshold. The `if (!knownCharacters.contains(character))` is redundant, `if (!knownCharacters.add(character)) noDuplicates.append(character);` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Nevay, about the 2nd point, I thought so too, but for whatever reason that way returns wrong results - check it yourself (`"ana"` with just `add`, `"Ban"` with `add` and `contains`).

Comment: Sorry, typo in my last comment, it should be `if (knownCharacters.add(character)) ...`.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury thank you for you insightful response. I did not notice how much I could improve this code. One of the eye openers was the generics and specifying the size of the stringbuilder.

Comment: @TheLearner, Vogel612 had generics in his answer to your previous question (which you should link into your question), from which your current code was, ahem, "inspired". (Please give proper credits where due!)

Comment: Will do @TamoghnaChowdhury !